# Is the common eingenfunction between breit interaction and angular momentum antisymmetric?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics

The Breit interaction is given by
$$
H=\sum_{i=1}^N\left(H_i^1+H_i^2+H_i^3\right)+\sum_{i>j=1}^N\left(H_{i j}^4+H_{i j}^5+H_{i j}^6\right)
$$
Here
$$
\begin{aligned}
H_i^1 & =c\left(\alpha_i^{(1)} \cdot p_i^{(1)}\right), \\
H_i^2 & =\beta_i c^2, \\
H_i^3 & =V\left(r_i\right), \\
H_{i j}^4 & =1 / r_{i j}, \\
H_{i j}^5 & =-\frac{1}{2 r_{i j}}\left(\alpha_i^{(1)} \cdot \alpha_j^{(1)}\right), \\
H_{i j}^6 & =-\frac{1}{2 r_{i j}^3}\left(\alpha_i^{(1)} \cdot r_{i j}^{(1)}\right)\left(\alpha_j^{(1)} \cdot r_{i j}^{(1)}\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$
In these formulas the Dirac matrices $\alpha^{(1)}$ and $\beta$ are defined in the usual way.

By explicit calculation we can show that the total angular momentum $J=L+S$ commutes with $H$ and So we can find a Common eigenfunction $\Psi$ between $H$ and $J$.
But in atomic physics we need that  $\Psi$ to be antisymmetric.
How can we proof that $\Psi$ is antisymmetric?